# Function values ​at many points

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to receive the results of the function for 3 points. I would like x and y to replace the coordinates of three points to get 6 results - due to 2 values ​​of the coefficient "k". x and y are independent of x0 and y0, but in this particular case they are equal.

```
{x = x0, y = y0, {2, 2}, {2.3}, {5, 4}}

De[e_, h_, v_] := ((e h^3)/(12 (1 - v^2)))
Alf[a_] := ((m Pi)/a)
Bet[b_] := ((n Pi)/b)
q[p_, a_, b_, x0_, y0_] := ((4 p)/(a b)) Sin[Alf[a] x0] Sin[Bet[b] y0]
Delt[e_, h_, v_, a_, b_,k_] :=( De[e, h, v] (Alf[a]^2 + Bet[b]^2)^2+k)
w[p_, a_, b_, x0_, y0_, e_, h_, v_,k_] := q[p, a, b, x0, y0]/Delt[e, h, v, a, b,k]

Mx[e_, h_, v_, a_, b_, p_,k_, x0_, y0_, x_/;0<=x<=6, y_/;0<=y<=4] :=
  De[e, h, v] *
  Sum[
    Sum[
      ((Alf[a]^2 + v Bet[b]^2) w[p, a, b, x0, y0, e, h, v,k])  * 
        Sin[Alf[a] x] Sin[Bet[b] y], 
      {n, 1, 80}], 
    {m, 1, 80}]

k = {5*^6, 4*^6}

Mx[27000000000, 0.2, 0.2,6, 4, 10000, k, x0, y0, x, y]
```

Comment: This is *very* confusing.  Can you rewrite your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this:

```
De[e_, h_, v_] := ((e h^3)/(12 (1 - v^2)))
Alf[a_] := ((m Pi)/a)
Bet[b_] := ((n Pi)/b)
q[p_, a_, b_, x0_, y0_] := ((4 p)/(a b)) Sin[Alf[a] x0] Sin[Bet[b] y0]
Delt[e_, h_, v_, a_, b_, 
  k_] := (De[e, h, v] (Alf[a]^2 + Bet[b]^2)^2 + k)
w[p_, a_, b_, x0_, y0_, e_, h_, v_, k_] := 
 q[p, a, b, x0, y0]/Delt[e, h, v, a, b, k]


Mx[e_, h_, v_, a_, b_, p_, k_, x0_, y0_, x_ /; 0 <= x <= 6, 
  y_ /; 0 <= y <= 4] := 
 De[e, h, v]*
  Sum[Sum[((Alf[a]^2 + v Bet[b]^2) w[p, a, b, x0, y0, e, h, v, 
        k]) Sin[Alf[a] x] Sin[Bet[b] y], {n, 1, 80}], {m, 1, 80}]

k = {5*^6, 4*^6}
pairs = {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 4}}

Mx[27000000000, 0.2, 0.2, 6, 4, 10000, #1, Sequence @@ #2, 
   Sequence @@ #2] & @@@ Tuples[{k, pairs}]
```

which gives:

> `{4129.19, 3847.55, 0., 4162.98, 3866.17, 0.}`

Comment: Thank you for answer